# jQuery on list item hover, show delete button for that individual item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a preview of what I have:

---

[image]

---

On the right is when I hover.  What I want is for the delete icon to only show for that hover item.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $(".removeService").hide();     

    // Deleting an Individual Service
    $("#dashboard ul li span").hover( function() {
        $(".removeService").show();
    });

});
</script>
```

This is probably a very simple fix, but if anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $(".removeService").hide();     

    // Deleting an Individual Service
    $("#dashboard ul li span").hover( function() {
        $(this).find(".removeService").show();
    });

});
</script>
```

This assumes that `.removeService` is nested within `#dashboard ul li span`.  If this is not the case, please provide your html.

In the code `this` is the actual `span` which is hovered on.  `find` will search within that span for all elements with the `removeService` class.

Comment: awesome, thank you! what about when you hover out, is there a function for that to then hide it?

Comment: If it's not nested within, rather than `.find()`, he'll probably want `.siblings(".removeService");`.

Comment: @Drew, then you'll want `.mouseleave();`.

Comment: `hover` takes a 2nd parameter which is the function to run when your mouse leaves the element.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the delete span to show only when hovered over and hidden when the mouse exits, you can use an 'overload' for the `.hover()` function by providing a second function that hides the delete span.

See this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/Yz5Vf/) for an example.

A very simplified example could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remoteService').hide()
        .click(function(){alert('delete!');});

    $('#dashboard ul li span').hover(
    function(){  //this is fired when the mouse hovers over
        $(this).find('.remoteService').show();
    },
    function(){  //this is fired when the mouse hovers out
         $(this).find('.remoteService').hide();
    });

});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

Used `image` tag instead of `background-image`(see DEMO link at the bottom) to make it click-able.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/ga3Gg/3/)** here.

---

Why not use CSS `:hover` to get the same effect.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/ga3Gg/2/)** here

Comment: I think the `x` is supposed to be clickable, so a background won't work.  A similar idea should work though with an image.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - This is misleading - OP says :"What I want is for the delete icon to only show for that hover item". But the title says "Delete button".

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading into it a bit, but I think he wants a delete button to show up that can be clicked to delete the item.  Still +1 for the use of `:hover`, it can still work with an image.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: True, Thanks for the comment. I updated the demo :) with an image.

Answer (score 1):

You  have to do this with jQuery, you can achieve the same behavior with pure CSS:

```
#dashboard ul li .removeService {
    display: none;
} 

#dashboard ul li:hover .removeService {
    display: inline;
}
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/CbWGW/)